# TABS.Upload question in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, activex

I can't find any documentation about it except the examples.
I'm trying to use their server side uploading component and I would like to save a file with another. There is no SaveAs function.
What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not in the main object.
It's inside UploadObject.Form("FormName").SaveAs.
Took me a while to figure it out.